# Setting jQuery attribute for font-weight

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the font-weight of an element. I tried with the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#opt_" + i).attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

Also what's the difference between prop and attr? Is that something to do with my problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function instead of .attr()

```
$("#opt_" + i).css("font-weight", "bold")
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not an attribute, but CSS:

```
$("#opt_" + i).css("font-weight", "bold");
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/ENwbn/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#opt_" + i).style("font-weight", "bold");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also what's the difference between
>   prop and attr?

according to the [relase notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/) `.prop()` should be used for dom-properties, whereas `.attr()` should be used for html-attributes:

> First, using the .attr() method on the
>   window or document did not work in
>   jQuery 1.6 because the window and
>   document cannot have attributes. They
>   contain properties (such as location
>   or readyState) that should be
>   manipulated with .prop() or simply
>   with raw javascript. In jQuery 1.6.1,
>   the .attr() will defer to the .prop()
>   method for both the window and
>   document instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#labelAmt').css("font-weight", "bold").css("color", "firebrick");
```

I just gave an answer because if somebody wants to set multiple properties in a single statement.

So rather than above statement, you can set with comma separated value. Here it is [syntax](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#setting-several-attrs):

```
$('#labelAmt').attr({"font-weight": "bold", "data-test-2": val2}); //you can set your custom attributes too.
```